# Conditional import of modules in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, import, conditional-statements, python-import

In my program I want to import `simplejson` or `json` based on OS being Linux or Windows. I take the OS name as input from the user. Now, is it correct to do it with a condition like this?

```
osys = raw_input("Press l for linux, w for Windows:")
if (osys == "w"):
    import json as simplejson
else:
    import simplejson
```

Comment: Why are you taking the os name as input from the user?  Look into the platform module. http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html  `platform.platform()` or `platform.system()` should do what you need, rather than having a user have to input something every time the code is run.

Comment: @S.Lott: seriously? You do know that up/downvotes are meant to reflect the quality of the *question*, right? And not whether you agree with something *else* in the OP's code.

Comment: @jalf: It's a bad question in every way except grammar.  It should not be found as a top response to any kind of search.

Comment: @S.Lott there is nothing wrong with wanting to know if conditional imports are pythonic. And obviously others agree since it has +50 up votes despite your efforts.

Comment: Related principles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python

Comment: The operating system is **not a good reason** to choose between `json` and `simplejson`. `json` is in the standard library since 2.6; `simplejson` is a third-party library. The reasons to look for `simplejson` are because it's **needed** (older Python version) or **preferred** (consciously installed by the user to take advantage of extra functionality). Whether or not `simplejson` is available, has **nothing to do with** the operating system.

Comment: "there is nothing wrong with wanting to know if conditional imports are pythonic." Yes, but there is everything wrong with proposing to condition on something nonsensical, because that invites **unrelated answers** about figuring out what to condition on.

Answer (score 243):

I've seen this idiom used a lot, so you don't even have to do OS sniffing:

```
try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json
```

Comment: You should first try to import `simplejson as json` as it is likely a newer (faster) version of the standard `json` module.

Comment: or ```ujson``` for speed

Answer (score 79):

To answer the question in your *title* but not the particular case you provide, it's perfectly correct, tons of packages do this.  It's probably better to figure out the OS yourself instead of relying on the user; here's pySerial doing it as an example.

[**`serial/__init__.py`**](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/v3.4/serial/__init__.py#L21-L33)

```
import sys

if sys.platform == 'cli':
    from serial.serialcli import Serial
else:
    import os
    # chose an implementation, depending on os
    if os.name == 'nt':  # sys.platform == 'win32':
        from serial.serialwin32 import Serial
    elif os.name == 'posix':
        from serial.serialposix import Serial, PosixPollSerial, VTIMESerial  # noqa
    elif os.name == 'java':
        from serial.serialjava import Serial
    else:
        raise ImportError(
            "Sorry: no implementation for your platform ('{}') available".format(
                os.name
            )
        )
```

This should be only used in cases where you're assuming and need a strong guarantee that certain interfaces/features will be there: e.g. a 'file' called `/dev/ttyX`. In your case: dealing with JSON, there's nothing that is actually OS-specific and you are only checking if the package exists or not. In that case, just `try` to import it, and fall-back with an `except` if it fails:

```
try:
    import some_specific_json_module as json
except ImportError:
    import json
```

Comment: No, it's very incorrect to hardcode OS names to decide whether `simplejson` or `json` is available.  You're quoting code from *inherently OS-specific* imports, which is a very different case.  See Matt's answer for the correct approach.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: I'd defer to you then; I've never used the `json` package and was trying to answer the more general "can you do conditional imports of modules" question.

Answer (score 13):

It is not advisable to use to bind json or simplejson with OS platform. simplejson is newer and advanced version of json so we should try to import it first.

Based on python version you can try below way to import json or simplejson

```
import sys
if sys.version_info > (2, 7):
    import simplejson as json
else:
    import json
```