# Conditional compilation in python

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to implement conditional compilation in python similar to [this in C](http://ideone.com/ttndK),I have seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560040/conditional-compilation-in-python) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496592/conditional-import-of-modules-in-python).

But [this](http://ideone.com/u7BO8) is not working. I am relatively new to python,how can we fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to use this to submit solutions to an online judge. For gcc, the judge machine supplies a paramater `-D ONLINE_JUDGE`. This has the same effect as having the following in your code:

```
#define ONLINE_JUDGE
```

Python does not have a preprocessor. So there is no way of defining a macro (in the same sense as in C) either within your code or from the command line when you invoke the interpreter. So, I think it is unlikely that the online judge provides a similar option for Python. But it might provide something as a command line argument that you might be able to use via `sys.argv[1:]`. Check the command used to invoke Python (must be mentioned somewhere on their website) at the online judge.

Comment: I checked [here](http://www.codeforces.com/blog/entry/79), so i guess I have to make the arrangement myself. Thanks.

Comment: @Tretwick Marian: Ah CodeForces :). You can request for them add a parameter to their command line. They are quite receptive about feedback.

Comment: It's not just codeforces only,I guess the standard is pretty much same for all other judges like spoj and sgu, I am more active in spoj however:-)

Answer (score 2):

A bit too heavy for my taste. How about this one:

```
import sys
try: fin = open('Problem.in')
except: fin = sys.stdin
```

Universal and really convenient per se. Two in one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the ONLINE_JUDGE variable - this is an "if", not really an "ifdef".

```
ONLINE_JUDGE = 0
if ONLINE_JUDGE:
    import math
```

Comment: No,the ONLINE_JUDGE is defined to be true in the online judges then this won't work I guess.

Comment: @Tretwick: That comment makes no sense. Names do not simply "appear"; either they are defined, or they are imported.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: I said that names is defined to be true in online judges read my comment carefully.The original site seems down check out this [cached](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:xxdOhpKUYYQJ:acm.tju.edu.cn/toj/faq.html+%23define+ONLINE_JUDGE&cd=5&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in&source=www.google.co.in)

Comment: That's a C define. Python is not C.

Comment: @Tretwick Marian: from your link: "then you may try to read some problems and submit your solution in C/C++/Pascal/Java." - I don't think it supports Python.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams:No I python is not C but it is [written in C](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:P1mpxQ4d0aoJ:en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython+cpython&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in&source=www.google.co.in)

Comment: @Tretwick: CPython is written in C. Some other implementations are written in other languages.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams:What those other languages are written in ?

Comment: @Tretwick: Jython is written in Java. IronPython is written in C#. PyPy is written in Python.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: if CPython is written in C then PyPy is written in RPython. There is a significant difference between RPython and Python as programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

[codeforces.com](http://www.codeforces.com/blog/entry/79) ([linked in your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295442/conditional-compilation-in-python/5295515#5295515)) invokes Python scripts as `python -O %s`. You can detect it in your script via `__debug__`. Compare:

```
$ python -c 'print __debug__'
True
```

and

```
$ python -O -c 'print __debug__'
False
```

So you could write in your script:

```
ONLINE_JUDGE = not __debug__
# ...
if ONLINE_JUDGE:
   pass # here goes online judge specific stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [pypreprocessor](http://code.google.com/p/pypreprocessor/)

Which can also be found at the [PYPI (Python Package Index)](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypreprocessor) so it can be loaded using pip.

Your specific example would look something like:

```
from pypreprocessor import pypreprocessor
pypreprocessor.parse()

#define onlinejudge

#ifdef onlinejudge
import math
#endif
```

To adding a define via the command line is also easily accomplished:

```
import sys
from pypreprocessor import pypreprocessor

#exclude

# defined if 'mode' is found in the command line arguments
if 'mode1' in sys.argv:
    pypreprocessor.defines.append('mode1')

# defined if 'mode2' is found in the command line arguments
if 'mode2' in sys.argv:
    pypreprocessor.defines.append('mode2')

#endexclude

pypreprocessor.parse()

#ifdef mode1
print('this script is running in mode1')
#ifdef mode2
print('this script is running in mode2')
#else
print('no modes specified')
#endif
```

Here's what the outputs should produce...

'python prog.py mode1':

> this script is running in mode1

'python prog.py mode2':

> this script is running in mode2

'python prog.py mode1 mode2':

> this script is running in mode1
>   this script is running in mode2

'python prog.py':

> no modes specified

*SideNote: pypreprocessor supports both python2x and python3k.*

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of pypreprocessor*