# Load module with variable path in python 2.6?

Tags: python

My dev environment is python 2.6, so the importlib.import_module() syntax is not available to me. I'm trying to load a module with a path that is set by a variable; is this even possible in 2.6?

The background is that I'm polling a number of devices from different vendors, so in various directories I have wrapper classes, all with identical methods and return types, which handle the vendor-specific methods for grabbing the data I need. So based on the vendor, I might need to load "platform_foo.stats" or "platform_bar.stats", then call the same methods on the resulting module.

So, something like this, except this is obviously non-working code:

```
vendor = get_vendor(hostname)
vendor_path = 'platform_%s.stats' % vendor
import vendor_path
stats = vendor_path.stats(constructor_args)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496592/conditional-import-of-modules-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exec()` to execute dynamic code in python.

In your case, something like this should do the trick.

```
vendor = get_vendor(hostname)
vendor_path = 'platform_%s.stats' % vendor
exec("import " + vendor_path)
stats = vendor_path.stats(constructor_args)
```

I tried this on some built-in modules, and it seemed to work fine.