# How do you make program clear your console clean before it prints a list?

Tags: python

```
office_list = []
print("Type in your office supplies.\nEnter 'DONE' to print out your list.\n--------------------\n")

while True:
  list = input("> ")  
  if list == 'DONE':
    break
  office_list.append(list)

print("Here is your list\n--------------------\n")

for ls in office_list:
  print(ls)
```

I've been trying to find this online but seem to have trouble trying to find the correct vocabulary I believe.

What I am trying to make the program do is clear what I have written to make the list and then print the list. What happens in the program right now is it will have the words I typed on top of the list and print when I enter the word 'DONE'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear the interpreter console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console)

Comment: Perhaps it's better to run `clear && python foo.py`

Comment: @slezica I need to clear text while a program is run. Not when I'm trying to start the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just print enough newline characters like this:

```
print('\n' * 50)
```

It doesn't hurt to print out too many lines for a console application as this will all happen in a split second. This method is cross-platform and should work in nearly any environment.

The OS-level answers actually do the same thing, but the OS knows *exactly how many lines to print*. If you don't care about hiding the precise number of lines that are shown on the screen, just print out enough (within reason) to clear the console.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. I'm still having problems with using the OS-level answers atm. I might as well use print('\n' * 50) for now. I'll have to learn the OS commands one of these days.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `os` module. Under *nix, you can use `os.system('clear')` or `os.system('cls')` under Windows.

Comment: Additionally, you can programmatically determine what OS you are running with `sys.platform`. Then you can decide if you should use `cls` o `clear`

Comment: @GrayCygnus Better to use `os.name`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18476686/6655092

Comment: I get a syntaxError. Would using work spaces in team treehouse be the problem?

Comment: @pycoder not necessarily better, there are several alternatives, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854/python-what-os-am-i-running-on)

Comment: @GrayCygnus It doesn't matter if it is Linux or Mac OS X, just whether it is Unix or Windows.

Comment: @RussellAlson no, a `SyntaxError` means you are not writing valid Python.

Comment: @RussellAlson in case you were being sarcastic, I can't offer any more explanation without seeing the full error message.

Comment: @timgeb In no way was it used as sarcasm. It's honestly genuine. Still in a newby level right now and all the small details are nice to take in.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `os` module, you can run shell commands. To clear the console on Linux/macOS you can use the `clear` command, on Windows there's `cls`:

```
import os
import sys

def clear():
    if sys.platform == 'windows':
        os.system('cls')
    else:
        os.system('clear')
```

Comment: There is a systaxError: invalid syntax. Would this be because Team Treehouse doesn't support this?

Comment: try this @RussellAlson

Comment: It didn't work in team treehouse. It just passes by the def clear() function or it just didn't output anything. @enedil