# Conditional import a module in python with if-statement

Tags: python, if-statement, import

I have a code in production that requires to read certain modules if a parameter is given 1 and should not read certain modules if a parameter is zero. Here is a simple example:

```
global parameter
if parameter==0: 
   import numpy as np 

if parameter ==1:
   import pandas as pd
```

Is there anyway to achieve this in python? I cannot import both modules at the same time.

Comment: Yes, you can. Only you have to keep in mind to indent the code accordingly

Comment: can you please give an example? Does it work the way I write in my question? I thought i could not import like that

Comment: When I copy and paste your code, it works. What problem are you having with it?

Comment: See [Conditional import of modules in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496592/conditional-import-of-modules-in-python)

Comment: Importing Pandas will cause Numpy to be imported behind the scenes, FWIW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have here must work properly as is.

Comment: I don't understand what this means: that the OP's code as shown already works, or that it doesn't but it should?

Comment: sorry I never tested it myself because I never though this would work. Anyhow, thanks for clarification.

Comment: @smci my appologies for being unclear. Yes, it works as is